# How can I see utf8mbf collate for a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

Here is the command I use:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

It works well. Now I need to set `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for a column *(since currently characters are shown as `???`)*. Anyway here is my new command:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But sadly MySQL throws:

> ERROacR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER

Any idea?

Comment: `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Typo? `utf8` != `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the `COLLATION` name must match the `CHARACTER SET` name.

`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is needed for Emoji and some Chinese characters.

Let's back up to the 'real' problem -- of question marks.

`COLLATION` refers to the rules of ordering and sorting, not encoding.

`CHARACTER SET` refers to the encoding.  This should be consistent at all stages.  Question Marks come from inconsistencies.

[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) points out that these are the likely suspects for Question Marks:

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is not CHARACTER SET utf8mb4. Fix this if you need 4-byte UTF-8. (Use SHOW CREATE TABLE.)
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8. The details depend on the application doing the connecting.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```